# Back button refresh the current page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page called index.html, when I click the link in index html it will navigate to the another page which has Listview populated with data taken from Server. This Works without any error.

However, when I click the back button of current page, I will be directed to the previous page.

My question is, it refreshes current page and then go back to the previous page.
I need to prevent this.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script language="text/javascript">
                /* VERY IMPORTANT this is before loading jquery.mobile JS */
                $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
                    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
                    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
                    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
                });

            </script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
                    $("#mybtn").bind("click", function(e) {
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                        $.mobile.changePage("twitter.html", {
                            reloadPage: true, changeHash: true
                        });

                    });
                });

                $(document).on("pagehide", "div[data-role=page]", function(event) {
                    $(event.target).remove();
                });

            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="reviewsPage">

                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Reviews</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="mybtn" class="ui-btn-right" data-ajax="false" >TWEET</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**tweet.html**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="twitterPage"  >
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("pagehide", "div[data-role=page]", function(event) {
            $(event.target).remove();
        });

         $(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', '#twitterPage', function(){

        });
    </script>

    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Previous" >
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="tweet-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <p>
                    Tweets
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure it goes to previous page? your code removes previous page from DOM. What do you mean by "_it refresh the current page and then go back to the previous page_"?

Comment: Yeah i can go to the previous page(index.html).Refreshing previous page is my List View has only 2 items(Taken from server) when i click to the back it will add another two items and go back to previous.I think it   requesting data from server again

Comment: `$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data) {` this is being called again when you go back to index.html. add page id like this `$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', '#tweets', function()`

Comment: I change the code as you said(See my update).But nothing happen

Comment: for tweets.html, wrap your content in `<div data-role="page" id="tweets"></div>`

Comment: But i need to keep the tweet.html file in separate  file.

Comment: I know, this changes nothing. tweet.html is separate.

Comment: But if I have lot of pages  it is not easy to put all the pages on single page and maintain it. I would be glad if you can help me to figure out this problem

Comment: you dont need to put them in one html file. in all your html files, wrap HTML code in `<div data-role="page" id="unique ID"></div>` that's it.

Comment: I cannot understand can you show me a example if you can

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7y9dQ/

Comment: i did it you can see that on update.Still gives that error.I checked this on google chrome and ff.Have you checked the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unbind all events

```
 `  $("#mybtn").unbind();`
```